# Android Bluetooth - source code

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-source

I have been strugling with a Bluetooth project on Android for weeks.  Does anyone know where I can go to see the actual code that's used by Google to make their Bluetooth pairing and connection logic work?

I have been through all the documentaiton, the BluetoothChat application (which doesn't work as advertised ... tried it on 3 different handsets), as well as a bunch of other sites on the net, but still no luck.  I need to get an app up and running on 2.1 or higher.

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can browse all the android.bluetooth package around here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.java#BluetoothClass

Answer (score 2):

Ah, if you're having issues with application level code I'm not sure staring at the Bluetooth manager source will be much help, but here you go: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth the Bluetooth manager app code.

I'll re-iterate it: this is honestly probably not going to be helpful for what you want. You should be able to get a reasonably working Bluetooth app without having to look at this.

EDIT: if you want the code that implements the Bluetooth packages (android.bluetooth), see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth for that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the Bluetooth project didn't work for me also because the code for socket connection is not working

```
 // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                            MY_UUID_SECURE);
                } else {
                    tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                            MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
            }
```

this is not working ...

replace this by the following code

```
BluetoothDevice hxm = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(device.getAddress());
Method m;
m = hxm.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
socket = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(hxm, Integer.valueOf(1));
```